# Variants in astro not run

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion, astrojs

I'm learning Astro 3.0 and Framer Motion`these few days
and I have some error I can't resolve.

When I try **variants** in `framer-motion`.
The parent variants can run animate,
but children can't.

I tried **initial & whileHover** in every child, animate can run, but not run together like **variants** did.

I know Framer Motion is created for React so I write same code in a React component.
Everything works fine.

Is anything I missed in Astro file?

Here is my code
[code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/condescending-firefly-xxf2jn)

Answer (score 1):

I think i know why, but not sure.
so welcome any other answer.

i think `framer-motion` variants in parent element change will cause children elements re-render as new variant.

variants doesn't work in astro is because astro compile .tsx as static html.
so parent change won't cause children re-render.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).